# Invalid use of qualified name

Tags: c++, qualified-name

I'm trying the following:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace A
{
    extern int j;
}

int main()
{
    int A::j=5;
    std::cout << A::j;
}
```

But I've `error: invalid use of qualified-name ‘A::j’`. Please explain why this error occurred?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Please explain why this error occurred?

The language simply doesn't allow you to define namespace-scope variables inside functions. The definition has to be either in `namespace A`:

```
namespace A {
    int j = 5;
}
```

or in the surrounding (global) namespace:

```
int A::j = 5;
```

You can, of course, assign a value to the variable inside the function:

```
int main() {
    A::j = 5;
    // ...
}
```

but you'll also need a definition somewhere, since your program doesn't have one.

Comment: Where can I find that function body does not permit to define a namespace inside it? I'm looking for corresponding clause.

Comment: @St.Antario: C++11 3.3.3/1, "A name declared in a block is local to that block; it has block scope.". So you can't redeclare (and hence can't define) something at namespace scope within a block.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>

namespace A
{
    int j;
}

int main()
{
    A::j=5;
    std::cout << A::j;
    return 0;
}
```

Since you declare j in namespace A as extern in the global area, you also need its definition. But in main, you try to assign to it, which also need the symbol definition when linking. So you can remove the extern in namespace A, and remove the 'int' keyword when assigning.